# PyQt5 - Buttons become extremelly irresponsive when pressed with large data sets (10k)

Tags: python, performance, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to develop a small data acquisition GUI that is depicted below and everything works as intended for small data sets. This is how it is supposed to work: click "start/stop" to initiate or stop the trajectory plot from updating as well as the histograms. The trajectory gets the data from 2 txt files with 1 000 000 points each using python generators. After pressing the same button again it simply stops updating. That's about it. The problem is that performance starts decaying quite rapidly when approaching the 10 000 points on the system. But that decay in performance is only on the response of the system to the button pressing, the plots keep updating as it were nothing. How can this be? How could I solve it? Below I'll post some of the code that may help catch the error (I'll leave out the layout stuff)

I'm sorry for the long post.
[image]

```
def read_file(file):
    for row in open(file, "r"):
        yield row

    while True:
        yield None


def gaussian(x, B, mu, sigma):
    return B * np.exp(-1.0 * (x - mu) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    counter = 0
    XDATA = read_file("xdata.txt")
    YDATA = read_file("ydata.txt")

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        (...)

        self.map = pg.PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        (...)

        self.yhist = pg.PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        (...)
        self.xhist = pg.PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        (...)
        # Connect buttons to slots
        self.start_stop.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_data)
        self.fitButton.clicked.connect(self.fit)

        # Plot dummy data to map
        self.xdata = [0]
        self.ydata = [0]
        self.curve = pg.PlotDataItem(self.xdata, self.ydata)
        self.map.addItem(self.curve)

        # plot dummy data to xhist
        self.freqx, self.binsx = np.histogram(self.xdata)
        self.binscenters_x = np.array([0.5 * (self.binsx[i] + self.binsx[i + 1]) for i in range(len(self.binsx) - 1)])
        self.freqx = self.freqx / np.max(self.freqx)

        self.x_bar = pg.BarGraphItem(x=self.binscenters_x, height=self.freqx,
                                     width=self.binsx[2] - self.binsx[3],
                                     brush='r')

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 255, 0), width=2.5, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.fitLine_x = pg.PlotDataItem([0], [0], pen=pen)
        self.xhist.addItem(self.x_bar)
        self.xhist.addItem(self.fitLine_x)

        # plot dummy data to yhist
        self.freqy, self.binsy = np.histogram(self.xdata)
        self.binscenters_y = np.array([0.5 * (self.binsy[i] + self.binsy[i + 1]) for i in range(len(self.binsy) - 1)])
        self.freqx = self.freqx / np.max(self.freqx)

        self.y_bar = pg.BarGraphItem(x=self.binscenters_y, height=self.freqy,
                                     width=self.binsx[2] - self.binsx[3],
                                     brush='r')
        self.fitLine_y = pg.PlotDataItem([0], [0], pen=pen)
        self.yhist.addItem(self.y_bar)
        self.yhist.addItem(self.fitLine_y)

        # Set a timer for the update
        # make QTimer
        self.qTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        # set interval
        self.qTimer.setInterval(5)  # 1000 ms = 1 s
        # connect timeout signal to signal handler
        self.qTimer.timeout.connect(self.update)

    def start(self):
        start=0
        end=0
        current_counts=0
        if self.start_stop.isChecked():
            print("start")
            start=time()
            current_counts = self.counter
            self.qTimer.start()
            self.fitButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.clear.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            print("stop")
            self.qTimer.stop()
            self.fitButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.clear.setEnabled(True)
            end = time()
            print(end)
            print("FPS: ", (self.counter-current_counts) / (end - start))
            print("Total number of points read: ", self.counter)

    def clear_data(self):
        self.xdata = [0]
        self.ydata = [0]
        self.curve.setData(self.xdata, self.ydata)

    def fit(self):
        params_x, cov_x = curve_fit(gaussian, self.binscenters_x, self.freqx)
        params_y, cov_y = curve_fit(gaussian, self.binscenters_y, self.freqy)

        # plot it on the histograms
        data_range = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)

        self.fitLine_x.setData(data_range, gaussian(data_range, *params_x))
        self.fitLine_y.setData(data_range, gaussian(data_range, *params_y))

        # print the data to the tables
        (...)

    def update(self):
        # print(self.counter)
        self.counter += 1

        # update map
        if next(self.XDATA) is None:
            pass
        else:
            self.xdata.append(float(next(self.XDATA)))
            self.ydata.append(float(next(self.YDATA)))
            self.curve.setData(self.xdata, self.ydata)


            # update xhist
            self.freqx, self.binsx = np.histogram(self.xdata)
            self.binscenters_x = np.array([0.5 * (self.binsx[i] + self.binsx[i + 1]) for i in range(len(self.binsx) - 1)])
            self.freqx = self.freqx / np.max(self.freqx)
            self.x_bar.setOpts(x=self.binscenters_x, height=self.freqx, width=self.binsx[2] - self.binsx[3])
            self.fitLine_x.setData([0], [0])

            # update yhist
            self.freqy, self.binsy = np.histogram(self.ydata)
            self.binscenters_y = np.array([0.5 * (self.binsy[i] + self.binsy[i + 1]) for i in range(len(self.binsy) - 1)])
            self.freqy = self.freqy / np.max(self.freqy)
            self.y_bar.setOpts(x=self.binscenters_y, height=self.freqy, width=self.binsy[2] - self.binsy[3])
            self.fitLine_y.setData([0], [0])

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.fitButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Fit Gaussian"))
        self.start_stop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start/Stop"))
        self.clear.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear data"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your title uses the word "crash" but from the behavior you describe it sounds like the GUI just becomes unresponsive while the program is busy processing other work. Maybe you just need to move that work into its own thread.

Comment: Yes, in that case I'll correct the "crash", thank you. But could you explain a bit more why you think that's the case? I thought that the way the app's main loop worked was "Init main loop-> check for signals-> act on signals (run the slots)->repeat" so by that logic I can't understand why the "GUI just becomes unresponsive while the program is busy processing other work"

Comment: The GUI would be come unresponsive if the slots take a long time. Those methods are just called directly in the GUI thread (without doing some work to move them to another thread), so if they block, the GUI will block.

Comment: On that front, it looks like your `update` method is calling `PlotDataItem.setData` every 5ms, which is probably not what you want. That will clear any data on the item, and re-initialize it with the new data. This is a lot of extra work, given that only a single point has been added and none have been removed. Consider finding a more efficient mechanism for adding new points to the plot. Or, given that your monitor probably only refreshes every 16ms, reduce the update time :)

Comment: @bnaecker Thank you, if it may give you some insight, I ran a quick test and timed the time that each call of the update method took and I noticed that it became irresponsive when that time was about 2 to 5 ms (sometimes even higher). I can't help but notice that it is very close to the 5ms interval that I set. Are those two facts connected in any way?

Comment: Also, why do you say that " it looks like your update method is calling PlotDataItem.setData every 5ms, which is probably not what you want". Why wouldn't I want the 5ms interval?

Comment: To your first comment, yes, that's probably an issue. The timer events that cause the `update` method to be called are added to a queue; if the method takes longer to run than the interval at which the timer fires, the queue will only ever grow. To your second comment, you don't want a 5ms graphics update interval because nothing in your graphics system (or your visual system) happens that quickly. Your screen is probably running at 60Hz, so you're doing about 3 updates to the plot for each screen refresh. Two of those are unnecessary.

Comment: @bnaecker I just noticed that changing that 5ms interval to 10ms interval allows me to handle the 10k points, but that just delays the problem. I will check this update rate more carefully. Noting that this is intended for data acquisition from a sensor, can you reccomend any references that could help?

Comment: @Bidon [Pyqtgraph has examples](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/multiplePlotSpeedTest.py) of rapidly updating plots. I would only recommend separating out the data acquisition code from the plotting code, which will improve clarity, testability, and likely performance.